# Angular js $routeProvider works only on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my controller I have this structure

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap','pascalprecht.translate','ui.utils','ngRoute']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'languages',
    suffix: '.json'
  });
}]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/something/:firstparam/something2/:secoundparam', {controller: 'mainController'}); 
}]);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$translate,$routeParams) {
var init = function () {
    if ($routeParams.firstparam) {
        console.log($routeParams);
    }
};
setTimeout(function(){
  init();
},500);
```

And I try to hit `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#/something/1/something2/1` from browser first nothing happend and after that if I hit enter for the second time in refresh page and i get console.log of $routeParams object witch i need, but I dont want PAGE TO BE REFRESHED.

one more thing im not using partial templates, i only have index.html page and thats it, i realized  that routing wont work if i dont have "ng-view" somewhere in html so I created empty div and putted ng-view directive to it. Is that maybe causing a problem?